# Add button in a new row on datatable, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a javascript object, Im trying to add a new row to the datatable. One column is a field and the other column should contain a button.

```
var appendLastCategory = function() {
    var obj = {
        id: 'jh2i4h34ubi43',
        name: 'Lolo',
    };
    $('#categoriesList').DataTable().row.add({
        name: obj.name, //First column
        mRender: function() { //Second column
            return "<a class='md-btn' onClick='deleteCategory(this, &quot;" + obj.id + "&quot;)'>Delete</a>";
        }
    }).draw();
};
```

Then when I click in the "Delete" button, Im getting 'undefined' in the 'id' value. And I don't know why, because when I initialize the table filling it with the initial data and using the 'mRender' mostly the same way, it works.

```
var deleteCategory = function(element, id) {
    console.log(id);
    //Blah blah, all the code to delete on backend and remove the row
};
```

Comment: In the resulting markup, can you confirm that the resulting `onClick` attributes have the id listed? ie `deleteCategory(this, "jh2i4h34ubi43")`

Comment: I can confirm that even when I burn the 'id' in the code, it continues showing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help:

```js
var deleteCategory = function(element, id) {
  alert(id);
  //Blah blah, all the code to delete on backend and remove the row
};
var appendLastCategory = function () {
  var obj = {
    id: 'jh2i4h34ubi43',
    name: 'Lolo',
  };
  $('#categoriesList').DataTable().row.add({
    '0': obj.name, //First column
    '1': "<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' role='button' onClick='deleteCategory(this, &quot;" + obj.id + "&quot;)'>Delete</a>",
  }).draw();
};

$(function () {
  appendLastCategory();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



<table id="categoriesList" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>button</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>button</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response! I have resolved.

To initialize the DataTable, this is the following code:

```
var datax = [{
      id: '67i67i634r2r',
      name: 'Lala',
   },{
      id: 'g45y45y657t3',
      name: 'Lele',
   }];
$('#categoriesList').DataTable({
    "data": datax,
    "columns": [
        { data: "name" }, {
            render: function(o, type, data) {
                return "<a class='md-btn' onClick='deleteCategory(this, &quot;" + data.id + "&quot;)'>Delete</a>";
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

At the final everything got resolved just adding the javascript object in this way. Hope this will help more people.

```
var appendLastCategory = function () {
   var obj = {
      id: 'jh2i4h34ubi43',
      name: 'Lolo',
   };
   $('#categoriesList').DataTable().row.add(obj).draw();
};
```